# Accordion being opened from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanted to try and click on a link with a http://sample.com#sample after the html and open an accordion on another page onload. I have ran a few tests and wanted to have it go to the new page and then open the accordion. I could not get it to work. If possible can you tell me if the problem lies with this code?

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

 if (window.location.hash) {
   var AccordionSectionNumber = window.location.hash.substring(1);
   AccordionBodyID = $(".accordion .accordion-group:nth-of-type(" + AccordionSectionNumber + ") .accordion-heading a").attr('href')
      if (! (typeof AccordionBodyID === "undefined")) {
        $(#sample).collapse('show');
        return true;
      }
   }
</script>
```

Comment: There are a few problems in your code. First, `collapse` isn't a valid function. I think you mean `accordion`. Second, `$(#sample)` should be `$('#sample')` (notice the quotes, since it's a string). Also, what's the purpose of getting `AccordionBodyID` if you don't use it when selecting which accordion to open?

Comment: Im not experienced enough to make this work. It seems simple but everything I do doesn't help it work. Would you happen to know what I would call this or a place where there is a live sample?

Comment: <script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

 if (window.location.hash) {
   var AccordionSectionNumber = window.location.hash.substring(1);
   AccordionBodyID = $(".accordion .accordion-group:nth-of-type(" + AccordionSectionNumber + ") .accordion-heading a").attr('href')
      if (! (typeof AccordionBodyID === "undefined")) {
        $('#tester').accordion('show');
        return true;
      }
   }

});
</script>